# How to print out a pixel value in a Mat image

Tags: c++, opencv, pixel, mat

I have a question about how to cout a pixel value in an image.

For example: I have image and size is 10*10, I want to cout the pixel value at row 5 and column 5 in the image, here is what I code.

```
Mat img;
cout << img.at<uchar>(5,5) << endl;
```

But the result is in the following image
[image]

I'm wondering why it prints such strange symbol?

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: If your image has 3 channels you need `cv::Vec3b` instead of `uchar`

Comment: `cout << int(img.at<uchar>(5,5)) << endl;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are printing char value. So the value will translate into ANSI representation of that value. If you want to see a number, cast the result:

```
static_cast<int>(img.at<uchar>(5,5))
```

Comment: Great find J. Marek, but your first solution was wrong, it would mix the pixel with other pixels.